# How to check the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n/2}}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, factorial

How do I know the nature of the

> $$\begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^{n/2}}{n!}
> \end{align}$$

I have tried the ratio test and got nowhere.

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: Hint: in the ratio test, $(n+1)^{n/2}/n^{n/2} = (1+1/n)^{n/2} \to e^{1/2}$.

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I didm maybe I did something wrong,idk.

Comment: btw, usually including the details of what you tried rather than mentioning what you tried usually help you learn better as we can point out where do you make the mistake.

Comment: $n!\geq\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$, so...

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{n+1}2}}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{n!}{n^\frac{n}2} &= \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}\sqrt{\left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}\sqrt{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}
\end{align}

I am going to leave the evaluation of the limit as $n\to \infty$ as an exercise.

Comment: I have verified that the limit is not 1. As a hint, you will want to take the limit of the logarithm, and then do $\exp$ at the end.